# How to format json to what I need?

Tags: php, json, formatting

ok, Going to get this out of the way right now. I suck at php. I am building an angular app that is going to populate a mobile app with data from the database. I having it pull from the database just fine but I need the json formatted in a special way and I have no idea how to do it.

Using json_encode this is how it is coming from the database:

```
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "date":"2014-10-03",
    "time":"2014-10-03 10:45:05",
    "amount":"5"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "date":"2014-10-03",
    "time":"2014-10-03 12:21:05",
    "amount":"2"
  }
]
```

This is how I need it organized (this is just dummy data im using in on the angular side)

```
  [
    {
      date: '2014-09-04',
      feeding: [
        {
          id: '1',
          time: '1409852728000',
          amount: '3'
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          time: '1409874328000',
          amount: '4'
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      date: '2014-09-05',
      feeding: [
        {
          id: '3',
          time: '1409915908000',
          amount: '3.5'
        },
        {
          id: '4',
          time: '1409957908000',
          amount: '5'
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
```

I needs to be seperated out and grouped by date.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you don't format json. you build a native php array and then ENCODE it to json.

Comment: Thanks Marc. See how noob I am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airtech was just about there. Small update to the function though. The feeding value needs to be an array of objects rather than an object. You then need to push individual objects into that array.

```
function dateparse($in) {
$in = json_decode($in);
$out = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($in); $i++) {
    $date = $in[$i]->date;
    $isFound = false;
    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < sizeof($out); $i2++) {
        if ($date == $out[$i2]["date"]) {
            // We've already run into this search value before
            // So add the the elements
            $isFound = true;
            $out[$i2]["feeding"][] = array(
                "id" => $in[$i]->id,
                "time" => $in[$i]->time,
                "amount" => $in[$i]->amount);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$isFound) {
        // No matches yet
        // We need to add this one to the array
        $feeding = array("id" => $in[$i]->id, "time" => $in[$i]->time, "amount" => $in[$i]->amount);
        $out[] = array("date" => $in[$i]->date, "feeding" => array($feeding));
    }
}
return json_encode($out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?  I tested it on your json input example and it ran fine.

```
function parse($in)
{
    $in = json_decode($in);
    $out = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($in); $i++) {
        $date = $in[$i]->date;
        $isFound = false;
        for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < sizeof($out); $i2++) {
            if ($date == $out[$i2]["date"]) {
                // We've already run into this search value before
                // So add the the elements
                $isFound = true;
                $out[$i2][]["feeding"] = array(
                    "id" => $in[$i]->id,
                    "time" => $in[$i]->time,
                    "amount" => $in[$i]->amount);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$isFound) {
            // No matches yet
            // We need to add this one to the array
            $out[] = array("date" => $in[$i]->date, "feeding" => array(
                    "id" => $in[$i]->id,
                    "time" => $in[$i]->time,
                    "amount" => $in[$i]->amount));
        }
    }
    return json_encode($out);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, all that I got from this was an empty json. Thanks though :)

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to rename $a to $in in all instances (I used just $a in writing it up, but "in" is better worded). I corrected it for reference.

Comment: I will try this back home and see how it goes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? This works fine and works as expected :) :-

```
function dateparse($var)
    {
        $counter=0; $var = json_decode($var); $date=array();
        foreach($var as $key=>$value){foreach($value as $val1=>$val2)
            {if($val1 == "date")
                {foreach($value as $val3=>$val4)
                        {if($val3!="date") //because we don't want date again
                            {
                            $date[$val2]["feeding"][$counter][$val3] = $val4; continue;
                            }}continue;
                }
        }$counter++;}
        return json_encode($date);}
```

Comment: Will this add to a group if multiple dates are found?

Comment: You can test with some 10-15 sample records. I tried. It works the way you wanted. :)

Comment: I would note that while it's the accepted answer and it works, it's also inefficient - you have 3 full for loop iterations in here with no conditional breaks. I did update my suggested one down below. 

Also would be great if it was edited for formatting - multiple commands on the same line.

Comment: improved it some bit ! :)

Comment: This wasn't outputting what I needed actually.